# Time Series Anomaly Detection Across Multiple Dimensions

Tags: python, time-series, anomaly-detection

I'm working on a project where I'm tasked to find anomalous data (count of people) across different dimensions (categorical i.e country, occupation and a few more) and different days.

Below is a sample of the data

[count is count for people per day, country and occupation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9aNh.png)

How do I go about this? Any recommended Python libraries or models? I found lots of tutorials on multivariate time series analysis but my data isn't multivariate time series as the categorical variables in this dataset do not depend on time.

Comment: The count of people depends on time. Why do you say it is not a time series?

Comment: It is a time series. Not multivariate though, no? I think this is a multiple time series problem and I'm not sure how to go about it. I have a large number of countries/occupations.

Comment: Easiest is to consider each country/occupation as independent groups - and model only inside these groups. Then each one of those is a simple univariate time series. Leveraging data between groups is much harder

Comment: This is where I'm currently at but I was hoping to find a more efficient way as I have about 7000 occupation and 25 countries. That's a lot of independent groups.

Comment: See Bayesian Dynamic Modeling: Sharing Information Across Time and Space for an approach
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVPikT58meg

Answer (score 0):

You can try with LSTM, BiRNN, GRU with multivariable time-series prediction.
You can use tensorflow or pytorch to build the model.

Comment: Can you please check my response to Chiel and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn has multiple possibilities. You could take a look at [Isolation Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html).

Comment: My problem is I have multiple time series. The same date could have multiple counts. If you look at December 4th in the attached image, you'll see there are two counts (one for each country/occupation combination). So this is multiple time series correct? Would I need to impalement a separate anomaly detection model for each unique combination? I have about 7000 occupation and 25 countries. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: That completely depends on your use case. I can imagine that in your case the you want to group by occupation id or occupation id & country id to determine the anomalies in count. In a practical way I would determine a couple anomalies by hand (just by looking at the data) and check an out-of-the-box implementation removes those.

Comment: Yep I'm grouping by country and occupation, but this data is frequently used and updated so I would like to go for an automated approach instead of manually checking for outliers.

Comment: You are using pandas right?

Comment: Yes Pandas and my data is stored in mySQL tables

Comment: If you create a function which takes in the dataframe and returns the dataframe without outliers you can automate it. In this function you could determine the filters automatically based on the dataframe.